# Storing '\n' in Sql using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to store a string containing '\n' in Sql using Java. But the problem is in the database instead of \n a new line is getting stored.

e.g the string is "abcd\nefgh" then the database it is getting stored as

abcd
efgh

I had the same issue when i was storing such things using php i overcame that using mysqli_escape_real_string()

How can i overcome this problem in java?
please help.

Comment: If you want to store the absolute character try escaping it `\\n`

Comment: \n is already a newline character in Java, not only in your Database. Try printing to your console and you will see.

Comment: actually i have printed the query to console and the output shows that the query have \n in between and not a new line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But the problem is in the database instead of \n a new line is getting stored.

Well it sounds like the string itself probably contains a newline. If you write:

```
String x = "a\nb";
```

in Java, then that is a string with 3 characters:

- 'a'
- newline
- 'b'

That *should* be stored as a string of 3 characters in the database. When you fetch it back, you'll faithfully get a string of 3 characters back. The database will simply store what you give it.

Now if you're saying that you're trying to store a string which actually contains a backslash followed by an `n`, and that is being converted to a newline somewhere, then you'll need to post some code to show what you're doing. For example, I could imagine that *might* happen if you're including the value directly in your SQL statement instead of using parameterized SQL. (*Always* use parameterized SQL.)

So basically, either it's actually not a problem at all, or you should post some code.

EDIT: Now we've seen this:

> I had the same issue when i was storing such things using php i overcame that using mysqli_escape_real_string()

It sounds like maybe you *are* just facing a problem of inappropriate inclusion of values in a SQL statement. If you're using something like:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE FOO VALUES ('" + text + "')";
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

then you need to stop doing that. You should use:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE FOO VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, text);
statement.execute();
```

(With appropriate code for closing the statement and connection, e.g. the try-with-resources statement in Java 7.)

Comment: But it is not doing so i am fetching that string using php to display in the webpage but the string gets into new line instead of having \n in between. I checked through phpmyadmin.In the database it is storing a new line only and not \n as a character in between

Comment: @user8332: You still haven't told us where the original text was coming from though - it sounds like it probably *started* with a newline in, it's just you were seeing it as a `\n` in the debugger or something similar. You also still haven't shown us any code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: actually i have a part of C code as string which contains something like "printf("%lld\n")".Now i want to store it in database using Sql through java. But in database it is getting stored as
"printf("%lld <br>
")"
sorry i have used <br> to denote a new line.. never mind

Comment: @user8332: So if the text actually contains a backslash and an `n`, then if you use a prepared statement all should be well. See my answer for details. You *still* haven't shown us any of your Java code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: yeah i did not know about prepared statement and was using as u stated in the first. So if i use the prepared statement will it solve the problem which i am facing? i don't think so because the string remains the same.
btw thanks for that.

Comment: @user8332: Yes, it will solve the problem - as well as fixing SQL injection vulnerabilities. The string remains the same, but it's no longer being interpreted as part of SQL. You should *always* use parameterized SQL.

Comment: @JonSkeet: really thanks a lot. it solved the problem and from now onward i will always use Prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting "Always use parameterized SQL". This resolved my similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

\n is a new line character. If you want to store such combination as text you have to escape `\` so I guess that you have to store `\\n` for every `\n` occurence in targeted string. Escape character can be depandant to DBMS though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to double escape the backslash, if you don't work with parameterized  queries but do a raw insert (I would not recommend that), since it is a keyword in mysql, too.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('Hello\\\\nWorld')";
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to guide the OP towards parameterized SQL rather than giving them a workaround.

Comment: @Jon - I aggree, but the information that a backslash is also a mysql could help solving the problem. And you don't know the whole code. If the OP is just calling a method `product.SetDescription(1, "Hello\\nWorld")` from a class that he can't modify just changing the line to `product.SetDescription(1, "Hello\\\\nWorld")` gets the job done.

Comment: It fixes that issue, while leaving a SQL injection attack wide open... a problem you didn't mention. Parameterized SQL is by far the best solution here, and until we've got any evidence that it really *can't* be used by the OP, I'd avoid suggesting anything else.